# Conditional math in LINQ Select statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following select:

```
q.Select(c => new SomeObject
    {
        Invoices = c.SomeList.Sum(sl => sl.SomeValue),
        Payments = c.OtherList.Sum(ol => ol.OtherValue),
        Balance = ??? // Should be Payments - Invoices
    });
```

I'd like to calculate and return the Balance together with the rest of the object but can't figure out how to do it inside of the select statement. Thanks!

Comment: you can do this...q.Select(c => new SomeObject
    {
        Balance =  c.OtherList.Sum(ol => ol.OtherValue)-c.OtherList.Sum(ol => ol.OtherValue)
    });

Comment: Let `SomeObject` build itself up.  Give it a constructor: `q.Select(c => new SomeObject(c));`

Comment: Can't you do `Balance = c.OtherList.Sum(o1 => o1.OtherValue) - c.SomeList.Sum(s1 => s1.SomeValue)` ?

Comment: Could you change the `Balance` property in `SomeObject` to `public <type> Balance { get { return Payments - Invoices; } }`?  It doesn't seem like `Balance` should be a settable property anyway.

Comment: Is this an EF query or a LINQ to objects query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for anonymous types nor multiple iterations. Simply turn your Select expression into a code block and then use local variables.

```
    q.Select(c =>
                {
                    var invoices = c.SomeList.Sum(sl => sl.SomeValue);
                    var payments = c.OtherList.Sum(ol => ol.OtherValue);
                    // do stuff
                    return new SomeObject
                    {
                        Invoices = invoices,
                        Payments = payments,
                        Balance = payments - invoices
                    };
                });
```

As @juharr suggested, you can also make `Balance` a read-only property that returns `Payments - Invoices`. This is the suggested approach if Balance does not need to be settable.

Comment: Both the comment from @juharr and your answer works, thank you! Unfortunately, I don't have enough points on Stackoverflow to like the juharr's comment, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You can introduce an anonymous type to hold your intermediate calculations and then create the `SomeObject` from this type:

```
q.Select(c => new 
              { Invoices = c.SomeList.Sum(sl => sl.SomeValue),
                Payments = c.OtherList.Sum(ol => ol.OtherValue)
              }
).Select(x => new SomeObject
              { Invoices = x.Invoices,
                Payments = x.Payments,
                Balance  = x.Payments - x.Invoices
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [let](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) clause:

```
var query= from e in q
           let invoices= e.SomeList.Sum(sl => sl.SomeValue);
           let payments = e.OtherList.Sum(ol => ol.OtherValue);
           select new SomeObject
                      {
                        Invoices = invoices,
                        Payments = payments,
                        Balance = payments - invoices
                      };
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't be done inside the select you need a 2nd select

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<SomeObject> q = new List<SomeObject>();

            q.Select(c => new 
            {
                Invoices = c.SomeList.Sum(),
                Payments = c.OtherList.Sum(),

            }).Select(x => x.Payments - x.Invoices);

        }
    }
    public class SomeObject
    {
        public int[] SomeList { get; set; }
        public int[] OtherList { get; set; }
    }
}​
```

Comment: It can be done inside of the `Select`. Also, this does not return an Enumerable of SomeObject. Instead, it'll return an Enumerable of whatever datatype Payments/Invoices is.